How can I get a all the files present in a directory with their hashes as a Dictionary in C#?
I have a directory countaining a lot of files (around 650 files) and i want to get all the files present in this directory with their hash (something like sha256 or sha512) in a Dictionary while seeing the percentage of the operation? Because I assume that it would take some time to hash them.

I suppose you want to hash content of files, not just their names, right?

Yes, their sizes vary from 1Kb up to 50Mb

You may want to consider trying this approach; based on similar cases, it has shown promising results and could potentially resolve the issue you're encountering.
    public static async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetFilesAndHashesAsync(string pathToDirectory, IProgress<double>? progress = null)
{
    var filesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    using (var sha = SHA256.Create())
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(pathToDirectory))
        {
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException($"Directory not found: {pathToDirectory}");
        }

        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathToDirectory).ToArray();
        var totalFiles = files.Length;
        double processedFiles = 0;

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(file))
            {
                var hashBytes = await sha.ComputeHashAsync(fileStream);
                var hashString = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", string.Empty);
                filesDictionary.Add(Path.GetFileName(file), hashString);
            }

            processedFiles++;
            progress?.Report(processedFiles / totalFiles * 100);
        }
    }

    return filesDictionary;
}



You may as well use GetFiles vs EnumerateFiles.ToArray

Instead of BitConverter and Replace, you can use Convert.ToHexString. Also why use Dictionary<string, string> and not Dictionary<string, byte[]> with a custom comparer EqualityComparer<byte[]>.Create((a, b) => a.SequenceEqual(b), a => new HashCode().AddBytes(a).ToHashCode())

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
